# How can I fix my 'for' loop so it loops until I type x?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char combo;
    int quantity;
    int ketqn;
    char ketupat;
    int sum;
    float protoprice;
    float orderprice, combp;
    float ketp;
    printf ("                  SATAY RESTAURANT                  \n");
    printf ("----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf (" Combo Type             Item                   Price (RM) \n");
    printf ("----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf ("   A        25 Chicken Satay + 25 Beef Satay      40.00   \n");
    printf ("   B        30 Chicken Satay + 20 Mutton Satay    52.00   \n");
    printf ("   C        10 Mutton Satay + 40 Beef Satay       46.00   \n");
    printf (" Add-on     1 Ketupat                              0.60   \n");
    printf ("----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf ("Enter combo type (A/B/C) : ");
    scanf("%c", &combo);
    printf("Enter quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);

    for(combo!='X')/*it says error: expected ';' before ')' */
    {
    switch(combo){
    case'A':
    case'a': combp = 40.00; break;

    case'B':
    case'b': combp = 52.00; break;

    case'C':
    case'c': combp = 46.00; break;


    default: printf("wrong input"); combp = 0;
    }


    detaildetails
    }


    printf("Add-on ketupat (Y/N): ");
    scanf("\n%c", &ketupat);

    switch(ketupat){
    case'Y':
    case'y': ketp = 0.60; printf("Enter ketupat quantity: ");scanf("\n%d",&ketqn); break;
    case'N':
    case'n': ketp = 0; break;

    default: printf("wrong input");

    }
    orderprice = (combp*quantity) + (ketqn*ketp);
    printf("Order Price = RM %.2f",orderprice);
    }
```

My problem is that the `for` loop doesn't compile.  It should keep looping until I type `x` but it doesn't compile.  How can I fix it?

Comment: A good read for you: [How to loop in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Use a while loop instead of `for`

```
while(combo != 'X')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (; combo != 'X'; ) {
   //your code
}
```

This is the correct way to use "for" loop in your situation.
The syntax of a for loop in C programming language is :

```
for ( init; condition; increment ){
  statement(s); 
}
```

In your code , you only need the **condition** , so **init and increment** part can be omitted.

Comment: while this might work, using a `for` this way is the bst way to get hated by a bunch of people...

Comment: I know what you are talking, but OP is asking how to use **for loop** , so I choose to answer this way.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get it to compile (see other answers) it will not work as desired.
It will loop forever or never execute the body.
To fix, add something to either the `increment` or to the body of the loop which changes `combo`.
You probably want to move the corresponding input reading into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use for in you program as single. like this`for(combo!='X')` For loop has syntax error. This is sample code for for loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int a;

   /* for loop execution */
   for( a = 10; a < 20; a = a + 1 ){
      printf("value of a: %d\n", a);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Learn more about tutorial point below link [tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm) your answer could be

```
for (; combo != 'X'; ) {
   //code you entered
}
```

Comment: tutorialpoint used to be a horrible place for learning c (at least a few years ago), they just made so many mistakes. I don't know if they fixed their problems, but I avoid the site.